# When you add the skin texture?Before or after retopology?

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting, topology, dynamic-topology

Noob question...I am new to sculpting and I was wondering when you add the wrinkles and skin texture, before or after retopology?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textures always after the mesh is ready.

And maybe as a tip, if you work with mirror modifier, then texture can be plied to half and mirrored(so drawing half the face gets a mirrored face), but if you like asymetric face futures (ea scars) then first apply the mirror then do your texture.